# UML Modeling - Does it become voodoo science in practice at some point?

Tags: uml

I am looking for insight on modeling. I had a intro course on Design Patterns and basic class diagrams, sequence diagrams, and use cases.

The class diagrams I have found invaluable as a tool of organization in my programming. The use cases are moderately useful so far.

This semester I am in a class going into UML in much more depth i.e. Domain Analysis, Requirements Analysis, Software Design vs. Software Engineering etc.

There is a certain feeling that this is starting to be more voodoo-sciencey or non-concrete when we start trying to be precise with the ambiguities in scenarios, and changing requirements. Is UML past basic class diagrams and use-case diagrams practically useful in **productivity** in most applications?

Comment: This should probably be community wiki, but I don't think I have permission to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *started out* voodoo. Diagramming software designs has always been that way. It is a way of showing in pictures what you want to say about the design in a human language. If it was precise enough to generate code from, we'd go ahead and do that and dispense with the coding step altogether.

The only thing UML brings new to the older ways is that it is a standard. Even then, there are so many different kinds of "standard" diagrams that I have to snicker a little when calling it a standard.

However, **the activity of design itself is extremely important** for all but the most trivial of tasks. The question is whether you are going to spend some time up-front designing your system, or if you are going to do it on-the-fly, after having written a great deal of wrong or unnesscary code. If you want things done quickly and/or well, you do some design up front.

This doesn't just apply to writing software BTW. It is an inherent part of any complex creative activity. My father-in-law, a retired English teacher who writes his children longish postcards when he goes on vacation, actually writes outlines for his postcard messages. Most master painters and sculptors make test drawings first.

Comment: it is great, when you can divide the idea from the substance:) UML is a great idea, but it has too many flaws in its substance, e.g. current standard.

Answer (score 2):

No.

All sorts and forms of documentation, are only useful as a means of communication. Documentation for documentations sake is a complete waste of time.

Writing UML is useful and productive only when it comes with a document that explains **(in words)**  what is it you want, why, and how. only then UML can help to illustrate what you are trying to say in the document.

Software teams that produce endless amounts of UML just for the sake of drawing squares, are just wasting time.

Answer (score 2):

You started out with modeling, which is a great thing to do, especially in computer science - you model all the time. Keep in mind UML is a standard for a modeling notation for software systems, nothing more (e.g. it is not an analysis or design methodology) and nothing less (e.g. it is not a way for developers to look productive by drawing nonsense).

You are on the right track, always keep in mind what is actually useful and gives you some value. This is not exactly relevant to your question, but sue cases are not use case diagrams, there are much more, have written form and might help you with much of what you described would be in your next course.

As to your concern, modeling is about abstracting from unimportant details, so some ambiguities might occour. The point is they should be unimportant for the purpose of modeling. For example it does not really matter if you include all the properties of your classes if you want to show the structure of design, e.g. use of some pattern. You can also use public properties without concerning yourself if they are private fields with getters and setters (Java), properties (C#) or generated object methods using metaprogramming (Ruby). The same holds for scenarios captured using use cases - of course you cannot (and should not try to) capture alternative branches using UML, but you can describe the conditions in use case descriptions just enough to avoid ambiguity without having to develop the system first and finding it is wrong afterwards.

As to the voodoo stuff - the problem is that UML is large and so many developers don't know how to use it right and often create more mess than value. Don't be confused by general disrespect for UML, the problem is in tool vendors, commitees and lazy developers... Behind many concepts in UML are well known formal models backed by academic science work, e.g. the state diagrams come from Harel statecharts (http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0167642387900359). So my opinion it is not as much voodoo in principle, it is just oversold with tools not supporting the standard and also the standard tries to be and combine everything (it is an unified language...), however this slowly improves.

My advice for you would be try to learn what is important - those formalisms, analysis and design methods, try them practically and decide for yourself what is useful. If for no other reason, learn UML because it is the language for analysis and design, although large, it is still better than its ~50 predecessors combined:).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience: Not really.

I never came across a really useful sequence diagram. Sequence diagrams stop being useful when the documented process becomes too complex, as you have a hard time following all the lines. But to understand a trivial process, I don't need a sequence diagram. When used as a design tool you will waste a ridiculous amount of time adjusting the diagrams, cussing MS Visio or whatever you use.

The notation however can be useful for a small snapshot when discussing something on a whiteboard. But this is valid for any notation style; UML is just well established, increasing the chances you are understood correctly.

Class diagrams are useful, both in design and in a posteriori documentation. But IMHO you shouldn't be too pedantic about them.

Answer (score 0):

Not in MHO. It's completely superfluous as far as I   am concerned.

Comment: As long as you do your design in some other way, then you are right. But design itself is important. Without it you (or I at least) waste loads of time coding yourself off in the wrong directions.